# Best Way to to compress mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, backup

I have a large mysqldump file on my server and I want to import it to my PC using FTP and it is taking forever as it is a large file.

I know there is a way to zip the contents of this file but I am not able to come-up with a precise command. What would be the best command to zip/compress a large mysqldump file?

Let's say the file name is backup.sql and it is in the folder named 'backup'.

Any help would be much much appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: So you are looking for a shell command?

Comment: mysqldump -u root -p database_name | gzip > dump.gz

Comment: @RahulTripathi that is an answer, not a comment. make it so

Comment: @d'alar'cop:- Added as an answer :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi I see it. +1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try something like this:-

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name | gzip > dump.gz
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Will get that a shot.

Comment: Also wanted one more clarification. I already have a mysqldump file on my server which is not compressed. Is there a way to compress this file? Can I use the following command: dump.sql | gzip > dump.gz

Answer (score 2):

If your database is large, you should add this to your mysqldump

```
mysqldump -u root --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false database_name | gzip > database_name.sql.gz;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your comment about existing files you can just do `gzip dump.sql` and it will create a compressed file for you at the current directory.